# Why is valueForKeyPath throwing NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, kvc

I'm debugging someone else's code so that's how I arrived at this point without knowing what this code does.

valueForKeyPath is throwing an NSInvalidArgumentException and crashing my app given the following code:

```
NSMutableSet *cars = self.allCars; //assume allCars is already initialized and contains at least one car.
NSString *key = @"make";
NSString *distinctUnionOfObjects = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.%@",key];
NSArray *makeArray = [cars valueForKeyPath:distinctUnionOfObjects];
```

I noticed that [the official KVC guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) says this in reference to the @distinctUnionOfObjects operator:

> This operator raises an exception if any of the leaf objects is nil.

So what is a leaf object in reference to my specific example? How do I trace which leaf specifically is nil?

Comment: It basically means that some object in the set, if sent the `make` message (in this case), returns nothing (`nil`).  To be honest, this *particular* Apple-provided operator isn't implemented in the most robust way and you're probably better off writing your own similar helper routine that can filter things while accepting `nil` values, etc.